# Wordpress Plugin - How can I make the text responsive, OR replace it with a new div?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, plugins, responsive-design

http://bit.ly/YqiQNQ

I have this food menu that looks great online. The menu is generated by a Wordpress plugin with customizable CSS. The rest of the site looks mint on the iPhone, but when you get to the menu it overlaps awfully and kind of disappears.

Open the link in the menu and make your window size really small - see how it overlaps at the smallest setting?

I was playing with @media on the widths and couldn't figure it out.

Can anyone help me make the text wrap around at the websites smallest width?
Or a plugin that will detect if the user is on mobile and display a different page entirely (just that page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having an issue with text not wrapping how you'd like it to wrap I'd suggest adding  `white-space: normal` to the text's parent element to ensure that the text will wrap and not inherit a `white-space: nowrap` declaration intended for another element.

For your specific circumstance, the following CSS will force the menu to wrap appropriately:

```
.rmc-menu-wrap {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I don't think it looks the best it could but it is better than it was.